# Bernoulli distribution and Strong Law of Large Numbers

Tags: inference, bernoulli-distribution, law-of-large-numbers

I'm trying to find concrete examples of the SLLN theorem. Before, let's see the statement of this theorem precisely from this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441923225), page 81:

> **Definition:** We say that $X_n$ converges almost surely to $X$, written $X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.} X$, if
>
> $$\mathbb{P}(\{s:X_n(s)\to X(s)\})=1$$
>
> **Theorem** (The Strong Law of Large Numbers). Let $X_1,\ldots X_n$ be IID. If $\mu=\mathbb E|X_1|\lt \infty$ then
>
> $$\bar X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.}\mu$$

I'm thinking about for example the $X\sim Bern(1/2)$, such as the coin experiment where we can define as $X(T)=0$ and $X(H)=1$.

The way I understand the theorem is it states for every $s$ in the outcome from the experiment (except the ones with $P(s)=0$), we have $\bar X_n(s)\to \mu$.

I can't see this in my example. Let's start with $s=H$. Since we already know $\mu =1/2$, we have:

$$\bar X_n(H)=\frac{X_1(H)+\ldots+X_n(H)}{n}=\frac{1+\ldots+1}{n}=1\nrightarrow 1/2$$

as $n$ goes to infinity.

Where am I wrong? Can someone give me an example that works in the Bernoulli's case?

Comment: You are taking an average conditioned on tossing only heads ($\bar X(H)$). This is a 'pseudo-average' since you will always get 1. The corresponding conditional (population) expectancy is trivially also 1, $\mu_{X|X=1}=E[X|X=1]=1$, not $1/2$ which is the unconstrained expectation $\mu_X$. The LLN never constrains anything. The unconstrained average $\bar X_n$ *will* converge to $1/2$ in probability (though this would be the WLLN).